# transform image in a bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transform

here is my problem, I have successfully encoded my bootstrap cards as I wish, but a small details grieves me.

I would like to make sure that the buttons 'infos' and 'mods' are not taken into account by "transform scale"

Only I can scratch my head and try all sorts of things I can not get out of this pass.

Here is the CSS & HTML code.

```
 <div class="card-deck row">

<div class="col-3"><!--event serv-->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card bg-inverse">
     <div class="card-block card-inverse event serv">
     <h5>Special event</h5><p class="lead">PVP / PVE</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/event serv-->

 <div class="col-6"><!--island serv-->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card bg-inverse">

     <div class="card-block card-inverse island serv">
     <h5>The island</h5><p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div><!--/island serv-->

 <div class="col-3"><!--scorched serv-->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card bg-inverse">
     <div class="card-block card-inverse scorched serv">
     <h5>Scorched earth</h5><p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>                                
</div><!--/scorched serv--> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.event{background-image: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/819/819763.jpg);background-size:cover;background-position: center;}

    .island{
    background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/91/6b/3b916b8b33b7aa08bf8fb920be2aa536.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    }

    .scorched{
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/819/819770.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;}

    .card{overflow:hidden;}

    .serv{position:relative;}

    .serv:hover{transform:scale(1.1);transition:all 0.7s;}
```

Someone know where my problem comes from? thank you very much !

Comment: what about the other text? Want it to remain static, too, and just scale the background image? Or do you want to scale the other text?

Comment: Hi, only scale image.

Comment: Only use bootstrap 4 css if its possible.

Comment: gave you a bootstrap 3 and 4 solution since I initially wrote it using 3. You should update your post saying you're using bootstrap 4 and that you aren't just looking to keep the buttons static - you want all of the text in the card static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the image to scale, move the `background` to an `::after` pseudo element of `.serv`, give the pseudo element a negative `z-index` so it's behind the text, position the pseudo element `absolute`ly, move the transition to `.serv::after` instead of only on the `:hover` pseudo class of `.serv`, and fire `transform: scale()` on `.serv::after` instead of `.serv`.

```css
.event::after {
  background-image: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/819/819763.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.island::after {
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/91/6b/3b916b8b33b7aa08bf8fb920be2aa536.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.scorched::after {
  background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/819/819770.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.serv {
  position: relative;
}

.serv::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.7s;
}

.serv:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck row">

    <div class="col-3">
      <!--event serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">
          <div class="card-block card-inverse event serv">
            <h5>Special event</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVP / PVE</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/event serv-->

    <div class="col-6">
      <!--island serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">

          <div class="card-block card-inverse island serv">
            <h5>The island</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/island serv-->

    <div class="col-3">
      <!--scorched serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">
          <div class="card-block card-inverse scorched serv">
            <h5>Scorched earth</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/scorched serv-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you're using bootstrap 4, give `.serv` a `z-index` so it's above `.card.bg-inverse` since that will assign a dark background color and cover the `.serv::after` `background` image.

```css
.event::after {
  background-image: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/819/819763.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.island::after {
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3b/91/6b/3b916b8b33b7aa08bf8fb920be2aa536.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.scorched::after {
  background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/819/819770.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.serv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.serv::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.7s;
}

.serv:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck row">

    <div class="col-3">
      <!--event serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">
          <div class="card-block card-inverse event serv">
            <h5>Special event</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVP / PVE</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/event serv-->

    <div class="col-6">
      <!--island serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">

          <div class="card-block card-inverse island serv">
            <h5>The island</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/island serv-->

    <div class="col-3">
      <!--scorched serv-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card bg-inverse">
          <div class="card-block card-inverse scorched serv">
            <h5>Scorched earth</h5>
            <p class="lead">PVE x 3</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Infos</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Mods</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/scorched serv-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer all :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Use :not(a) in .serv for translation. That should work.